# Incremental load of a full api call

Tags: sql, database-design, etl

I have an API I where I need to get signup data into my database from and aggregate it daily. Everytime I call the API I will get a full copy of the data. Sometimes old accounts will get deleted, so the historical data will change.

This is what the data from the API looks like:

[image: Basic data from the api]

I want to aggregate it like so, to see the daily account creations and activations:

[image: Aggregated data]

Now, what I could do is a daily import of the full data and then aggregate like this:

```
SELECT
Current_date() as snapshot_date,
SUM(CASE WHEN accountCreateOn = current_date() THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) as accountCreateOn,
SUM(CASE WHEN accountActivateOn = current_date() THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) as accountActivateOn
FROM full_data
```

But this doesn't seem very failure resistant. What happens, if the pipeline fails for a couple of  days? What would be the right way to solve such a problem?

Comment: If I have understood your explanation and question correctly, all you can extract from your source system is a current snapshot at the point of extract; you want daily summaries in your target; and you theoretically could have failures that cannot be corrected the same day. If this is the case then there is no solution - your source system cannot "magically" regenerate multi-day data. Possible solutions: ensure that your pipeline is fixable within a day when it breaks. Amend your source system so that it can provide  history of changes (log/audit files)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most fault-tolerant way is to store the data you are getting completely and as detailed as they are. You can't get any better information, and leaving away information - which includes aggregating it - always carries the danger that you will one day want to answer a question on those data that could have been answered on the complete dataset and can't be answered on the reduced one.

The only reason to leave this path could be datasets that are so huge that storing and processing them isn't feasible. For modern DBMS systems running on modern hardware, it's rather unlikely that you run into that problem. So I would create synthetic test data of the maximum size that I expect for my business, say 10 times the account activations per year that I dream of. If the database can handle this, it means you have one less problem to worry about.